# For what variables should you use weak var in Swift? How do I figure out the leaks?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I am building an app in Swift.  I am creating my views in an entirely a programmatic way.  In some instances, I have a ViewController that instantiates custom views.  In addition, I may have variables like "var User" which gets populated after an Alamofire network call and is used in various UI elements throughout the view controller.  Besides declaring delegates as weak var, are there any other rules that apply?

Also, is there a way for me to figure out whether I have a strong reference that should be a weak one?  What should I be looking for?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_memory_management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic concept behind reference counting in Swift is one of *ownership*. Objects should hold strong references to any other objects that they "own", in the sense that they're responsible for the lifecycle of the other object, either alone or in conjunction with other objects.

A lot of object reference graphs in a typical application are hierarchical - one object owns a bunch of other objects, which each have their own children, etc. For example, a ViewController owns its window, the window owns its views, each view owns its subviews, and each subview owns the images, strings, or other content it displays. These are all strong references.

Weak references will typically be used for references that don't imply ownership. The delegate example is a good one - in most cases, a view *does not* own the delegate. The delegate object has a lifecycle independent of the view. In many cases, the delegate will be the same object that created/owns the view in the first place, for example a ViewController.

You do *not* want a strong reference that goes from a "child" to its "parent". That creates a circular reference, and both the child and the parent will hang around in memory until the application exits.

In addition to delegates and other "backwards-pointing" references, you will also see weak references used in caches, where you want to quickly return an object if it's requested a second time, but the cache shouldn't keep the object in memory if nobody's currently using it.

Comment: What if I have a var User declared in an ExampleViewController.  But the User class does not even have a reference back to the ExampleViewController.  In this case, ExampleViewController has a strong reference to the User, but there is no retain cycle right?

Comment: Right. If there's no way for two objects to refer to each other, then there's no possibility of a retain cycle. Note that cycles can involve more than 2 objects, where A references B, B references C, and C references A. That's still a retain cycle.

Answer (score 1):

To *properly* answer your question, we would need considerably more detail, *(please ...)* added to your original question.

I would frankly caution you that "there are no *rules"* with regards to any issue as fundamentally "touchy" as weak references. Be especially careful not to "follow rules," imagining that thereby you will "be 'safe,'" when other aspects of your application's design do not *clearly* call for their use.

A "weak" reference is defined as a reference from one thing to another which, you assert, "is *not* sufficient to cause the referenced object to *not* be garbage-collected." If the memory-manager does decide to "reap" the object, it is supposed to set your "weak" references to `NULL`. It <strike>can do this at any time</strike> *will* do this at the most-inconvenient time.

One possibility worth contemplating in your application design is to use *properties,* backed by "getter" routines, instead of actual *variables.* Or, instead of storing a *(weak ...) reference to* something, put it into some sort of a "collection" and store its `id`. Yes, various forms of "getter routines" will be executed each-and-every time, but in the long run that might be more *reliable* than relying too-much on the memory manager. If you know that *"all* of the code, wherever situated," will have to pass through "this 'getter' routine," you can concentrate your bug-avoidance efforts at that one deliberate pinch-point.